# Should database value set back to default after computer reboot

Tags: mysql, database

I am using Windows 8, MySQL.

Firstly, I have some C# code which will generate an .exe file with some parameters.

Then, from that .exe file, I can change parameters. Once the parameters are changed from .exe, they will be changed in database as well.

Question is, database value on my computer is always set back to the default **after computer reboot. Is it normal? Or how can I keep the changed value consistency?

For example, the default value in db is a=0, and then I change it to a=1 from .exe GUI. However, after I restart computer, a is changed back to default 0.

Comment: This could happen if the value is set in a transaction and the transaction never commits.

Answer (score 1):

No, once a value is committed, it should survive a deliberate reboot, even using MySQL. This is one of the [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of database transactions. (*D* stands for durable.)

You can verify that by creating a database and a table manually, inserting some rows, updating some values, and restarting the computer. Doing this manually will isolate the changes from your C# code.

Your own code is the most likely source of the problem. Make sure you're committing all transactions.